Subfloor Joint - LVP
I failed to realize that 1/4” SurePly is 0.205” while 1/4 sanded plywood is 0.234”. Wondering if the difference will cause issues long term. Most other posts mention 1/16 being about the tolerance for transition points (between doorways) and this is less than 1/32. Since I’m not using a transition strip, the flooring will be continuous into the next room. One room has the 1/4” SurePly and the other has 1/4” sanded plywood.
Important to note the flooring is already down in most of the room, so a leveling solution (if warranted) would have to be in tube form to shoot under the floor. I didn’t notice the subfloor variance until I felt the slight dip on the finished floor.
Is this going to cause issues in the future if left as is?

Most of that type of flooring should mention how much floor height difference it can deal with.  I think most of them is a bit more than 1/16 or 2/16 and you have less than 1/32.  Really surprised that you can feel that difference.  What is the difference between the two floors if you lay a straight edge across the two?

@crip659 it’s about 1/16 when I put a level on it.

I would feather out the difference with some floor leveler and a large drywall knife.

Give the new flooring some time to relax and settle in.
It sounds like a joke, but LVP and LVT will conform to minor sub-floor surface variations given some time and use.  There should be no decline in useful life of the floor.
